# Computing Letter Grade and Adding it to a One-Dim arrary

Tags: arrays, if-statement, char, int, assign

In this section of programing I am trying to assign a letter grade to a numerical grade. I have done this before using if statements but this time I am trying to assign it into an array sequence. The array is of type char. scores[] contains the number grade.Im not sure of how to assign letters to an array. Im sure its a simple fix that I am just not thinking of. If you have any help it would be appreciated. Thanks

(score[i] has been determined in another method, and I know it works because it prints them in my output statement and i my computing average method, just didnt want to copy the entire code)

```
public void computeGrades (){
    if (scores[i] >= 90){
        grades[] = 'A';
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 80){

    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 80){

    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 70){

    }
    else if (scores[i] <= 60){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first `if` statement, you are attempting to assign the char `'A'` to an array. Instead, you should assign the `char` to a specific element in the array:

```
grades[i] = 'A';
```

You would follow this pattern throughout your other conditions.

```
if (scores[i] >= 90){
    grades[i] = 'A';
}
else if (scores[i] >= 80){
    grades[i] = 'B'; //I assume 'B' here
}
```

And so on.

One question, where are you getting the value for `i`?